# How does armor work?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I know that armor reduces damage taken, but how is this reduced damage calculated? Does it differ between weapon damage and condition damage?

For example, if I hit an opponent with a skill that does 100 damage, and that opponent has 100 armor, how much damage do I deal?

Answer (score 5):

The official Guild Wars 2 Wiki has an [article on damage](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Damage) (calculation).

**Edit:** I'll try to sum it up for you, as damage coming through depends on several factors.

The damage you deal can be raised if you score a [critical hit](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Critical_Damage): 1% crit dmg per trait point.
[Condition damage](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Condition_Damage) can also add to the total. +10 cond dmg per trait point.

Effective damage you do is also dependent on the level difference. Then there are the mechanics of [sidekicking](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Sidekick) and [scaling](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Dynamic_event#Event_scaling), the [Protection](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Protection) boon, [positioning](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Positioning), [projectile distance](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Projectile), ... that are all part of the complete formula.

**Update:** 
The wiki article has since been updated, and now contains an easy to understand formula to calculate direct damage.
It is

> **Damage done = (weapon damage) * Power * (skill-specific coefficient) / (target's Armor)**

Armor only mitigates direct damage, so condition damage and falling damage is not mitigated by armor.

Comment: Could you include a summary of the part that answers the question, so that we don't need to dig through the whole page to find it?

Comment: Armor is equal to Defense plus Toughness attribute, and will determine how much incoming damage will be reduced. (source: wiki; no harm in doing a bit of reading for yourself)

Comment: So basically it just says that armor reduces damage but doesn't give any details?  In that case, it doesn't really answer the question at all.

Comment: @Spatlap: Including the actual relevant text in the body of the answer is encouraged, and answers that are simply bare links to external sites are discouraged. cf. the FAQ: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion

Comment: I understand that, but I either give a simplistic answer like my above comment, not explaining it in detail, or either I give the complete answer, which basically would be copying the wiki article.   It's not as simple as the example the OP states, as there are some extra factors that come into play, like the Toughness attribute and the type of damage (whether it is armor ignoring or not).

Comment: You're correct. Apparently, the wiki article has changed since my post, and now contains a clear formula to calculate direct damage.  I'll update my answer.